# Android : Progress bar not shown even after setting visible.

Tags: android, visibility, android-progressbar

I am working on an Android project in which when user is uploading a image, I would like to display a progress-bar. But, even after setting that `show` the progress-bar, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Code :

```
 private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_restaurant_images);

        spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Rest of the non-relevant to problem code
}

      private void uploadImage(boolean profilePhoto) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (!(reducedSizeBitmap == null)) {
                reducedSizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                this.restaurantService.addRestaurantImage(byteArray, profilePhoto);
            }
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

XML file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userPhotoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="436dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.MaterialRippleLayout
                style="@style/RippleStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/main_color_grey_400">

                <internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/uploadUserImageButton"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyle.RaisedEmpty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/main_color_900"
                    android:minWidth="112dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="Upload"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.MaterialRippleLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Default"
                android:id="@+id/profilePhotoCheckBox"
                android:checked="false" />

            <internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.MaterialRippleLayout
                style="@style/RippleStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/main_color_grey_400">


            <internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/userPhotoButtonSelect"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle.RaisedEmpty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/main_color_900"
                android:minWidth="112dp"
                android:text="Capture"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
            </internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.MaterialRippleLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The image is purposefully around 6mb which I am uploading to see the bar, but it is not to be seen. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @MikeM. : Which one? I tried both, didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you have at least one call to    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in your code?

Comment: @StefanWanitzek : Yes, you can see in the code I have posted above, I have  spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); I have put the entire code here : http://pastebin.com/PbctN0ss   along with XML. Feel free to check it out. Thank you... :-)

Comment: In uploadImage() you are making it visible and then invisible again. How long will the execution of uploadImage() take? If it's just a few milliseconds you simply can't see it (or maybe reducedSizeBitmap is null?). Can you check that.

Comment: @StefanWanitzek : Execution of uploadImage() takes around 5-6 seconds as images are big(5-6Mb). reducedSizeBitmap is not null, image is getting uploaded in right directory on server, I can see that. Did you had a look at pastebin?

Comment: Sorry, don't see anything that's wrong.

Comment: @StefanWanitzek : It's my usage of Thread which is causing problem. Suhas's answer is correct, I have to change it to async.

Comment: @StefanWanitzek : I changed it to Async, but I still cannot see the Progress-bar. Can you please check this code : http://pastebin.com/rq8C1e9h  . Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this `uploadImage(boolean profilePhoto)` method `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);` will be called instantaneously and hence you are not able to see the progress bar.

Ideally you should use an `AsyncTask` like this

```
class UploadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Upload image here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would they be called instantaneously? The method will start, and the upload is with a Thread. I made this way, so I can verify if progress bar is shown.

Comment: Exactly, that method will start a new thread to upload the image and the UI thread will continue execution and sets the progress bar's visibility to `GONE`. Try adding some logs before setting the spinner to `VISIBLE` and `GONE` and you can observe that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will change it to async, and then check again.

Comment: Suhas : I tried using Async, but still no progress bar, here is code and XML : http://pastebin.com/rq8C1e9h

Comment: May be this link https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/ can help you.